# How to put 1997 Toyota 4Runner in neutral with dead battery?

Tags: toyota, battery, automatic-transmission

My ’97 Toyota 4Runner with automatic transmission is parked head first in a small garage with a dead battery. I need to put it into neutral to push it out on the driveway so I can jump-start it. (This is the same problem as the one in [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/793/prius-dead-battery-no-way-to-put-into-neutral), but unfortunately that answer doesn’t apply to the older Toyotas.)

Also, out of curiosity, would there be any safe/effective way to “daisy chain” two sets of jumper cables end to end, or is that just a Darwin Award waiting to happen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are the exact instructions from the owner’s manual:

[image]

[image]

Operations are the same except the item number three:

> If you cannot shift the selector lever out of “P” position to other positions even though the brake pedal is depressed, use the shift lock override button as follows:
>
> 1. Turn the ignition key to “LOCK” position. Make sure the parking brake is set.
> 2. Pry up the cover with a flat-bladed screwdriver or equivalent.
> 3. [2WD]: Insert the screwdriver or equivalent into the hole to push up the shift lock override button. You can shift out of “P” position only while pushing the button.
>
>    [4WD]: Insert your finger into the hole to move the shift lock override lever backward. You can shift out of “P” position only while holding back the lever.
> 4. Shift into “N” position.
> 5. Insert the cover.
> 6. Start the engine. For your safety, keep the brake pedal depressed.

Comment: That beats hooking a chain to it and just pulling it out a few feet. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well, as it turns out, I found my own answer on [another site](http://www.justanswer.com/toyota/1f1tf-battery-dead-put-corolla-neutral-move-so-jump-it.html):

> To release the shifter you will need to remove the cover for the shift
>   lock release button. Using a small flat blade screw driver pry up on
>   the cover, it is a small square cover located at the front left corner
>   of the shifter area just above the shift position indicator. Once that
>   is removed, apply the brakes and use your finger to push down the
>   release. While holding the release down, shift the transmission into
>   neutral.